# How to use "compared to"

Tags: phrase-usage, grammaticality

Is the following sentence correct?

> This text has altered significantly compared to original version.

Answer (score 3):

First, you should put the definite article before *original version*.

Second, the *compared to* clause is very frequently encountered in statements of this sort, but it’s wordy and in the end redundant. A comparison is implicit in the word *altered*; and in this particular sentence  it will be ordinarily taken for granted that the comparison is with the original. You need say only:

> This text has been significantly altered.

To be sure, if you are comparing multiple versions you *do* need to say which particular text you are comparing this one to; but that may be gracefully said:

> This text has been significantly altered from the original.

By and large, there is no need to mention the comparison explicitly if a comparison is implicit. *Tim is taller compared with Carol* is redundant; say

> Tim is taller than Carol.

Mentioning the comparison is only required if your statement is cast in the *positive* grade:

> Tim is **tall** compared with Carol, but **short** compared with Mike.

Answer (score 2):

I would write:

> This text has been significantly altered, compared with the original version.

About using *compare to*, or *compare with*, the NOAD has the following note.

> Traditionally, *compare to* is used when similarities are noted in dissimilar things: "Shall I compare thee to a summer's day?" To *compare with* is to look for either differences or similarities, usually in similar things: "Compare the candidate's claims with his actual performance." In practice, however, this distinction is rarely maintained.

As per the adverb, it should be closer to the verb it modifies.

Comment: What about **was**? `This text was altered...` would it be OK too? or should I have to specify the time?

Comment: Using the simple past is fine too, and it would not require to specify the time. Although, there is a difference between using the simple past, or the present perfect.

Answer (score 1):

It is almost correct.  You're missing the word "the" before "original version".  This would be correct:

> This text has altered significantly compared to **the** original version.

Now, to break the sentence down in more detail.  At some point, there was an original version of the text.  Since the time the original was written, it *has altered*.  Therefore the new text (in your sentence, referred to as "this text") *has altered*. How do you know it was altered?  By *comparing it to* the original text.  So yes--the sentence is correct.  The text has altered, and you know this by comparing it to the original version.

I notice other answers mentioned "compared with" as well as "compared to".  While I don't doubt that "compared with" is correct, I would say that personally it sounds odd to me.  I can't put my finger on why but I will say that, as a native speaker, I would use "compared to".  Just something that stood out at me. :)

Comment: has altered or has been altered. which is correct? Is "the" necessary? I think in some sentences "the" can be omitted.

Comment: Either "has altered" or "has been altered" is correct.  And yes, the "the" is absolutely necessary.  You need an article before the noun.