# "than compared to" or "than that of" in comparative?

Tags: comparative-constructions, comparative, subject-complement

I got stuck by the following sentence, which can be found [here](https://prod-edxapp.edx-cdn.org/assets/courseware/v1/b6060ce35070499ea9242f3bc6da813a/asset-v1:UTAustinX+UT.7.11x+3T2016+type@asset+block/Week_4_-_Optional.pdf):

> If we generate the column proportions, we can see that a higher fraction of plain text emails are spam(209/1195 = 17.5%) **than compared to** HTML emails (158/2726 = 5.8%).

I wonder if the complete sentence should be this:

*If we generate the column proportions, we can see that text emails contain a higher fraction of spam(209/1195 = 17.5%) **when (they are) compared to** HTML emails (158/2726 = 5.8%)*

The structure is obvious and the grammar is simple.

I don't understand why it should be expressed as "than compared to" since I thought this sentence would be correct and more comprehensible:

*If we generate the column proportions, we can see that a higher fraction of plain text emails are spam(209/1195 = 17.5%) **than that of** HTML emails (158/2726 = 5.8%)*

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["compared to" vs "than" - rewriting exchangeable](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6217/compared-to-vs-than-rewriting-exchangeable)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica This differs due to the subject matter.

Comment: I think this differs because it looks more like proofreading than the "original".

Comment: Throw out the syntactically irrelevant parenthetical elements in your final example, and replace ***a higher fraction of*** with syntactically equivalent ***more***. You're left with ***More** X emails are spam **than that of** Y emails*, which is obviously syntactically invalid.

Comment: The pronoun "that" in "than that of HTML" refers to "the fraction of HTML", so you cannot replace "a higher fraction of" with "more" and draw any conclusions. "A higher fraction of text emails are spam than the fraction of HTML emails" is syntactically valid

Answer (score 1):

"Than compared to" is an error. When drawing comparisons you would normally use *either* "than" *or* "compared to", and they are not necessarily interchangable.

For example:

- America has a **larger** population **than** Great Britain.
- America has a **large** population **compared to** Great Britain.

Use "than" when you are using a comparitive adjective like *larger* or a determiner such as *more, less* or *fewer*.

Use "compared to" when you are using a regular adjective like *large* and are just citing a second example for comparison.

Your example is a grammatical error. Clearly a comparison study has been made between the two kinds of email, but when presenting factual results (especially with specific numbers) you can plainly state that one number is *greater than*, or *more than* the other. That they are being compared goes without saying.

Note that in British English, we prefer "compared *with*", however the American "compared *to*" is commonly heard too.